# What is this bug and how do I keep it from eating my plants' leaves?

Tags: identification, bugs

Can someone tell me if they know what type of bug this is?  If so, how do I get rid of it as it seems to be eating the leaves.

<sub>*Click any photo for full size*</sub>
[image]

[image]

Comment: That's quite hard to see. If you don't have a better camera, try taking the picture through a magnifying glass.

Comment: Or at least get a picture on a more contrasting background if you can

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a katydid, which is any insect in the family [Tettigoniidae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tettigoniidae). Yours is from the  sub-family [Phaneropterinae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phaneropterinae). It's a [California Anglewing, *Microcentrum californicum*](http://bugguide.net/node/view/336585). It's probably not causing much damage on your plants, but you can control it with a general insecticide.

Here's a comparison picture:

[image]

Comment: My comparison pic even has the antenna missing on the same side. =)

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to see clearly, but it looks as if the body is shaped rather like an elongated leaf, with the back end narrowing down almost to a point. The eyes are definitely yellowish with black centres, it should have six legs, jointed in the manner of the two I can see in the picture - if I'm seeing it properly, this is a green katydid, and its one of those that does eat plants - usually sticks around on whatever plant it likes most and eats that. Presumably there is some local treatment appropriate for these if you have a heavy infestation, I'm in the UK, so don't know what you'd use - maybe someone else can advise on a suitable pesticide, if its necessary.

Comment: @J.Musser I could see most of it (on my desktop) but  couldn't quite distinguish between the greens for overall body shape - don't forget, my eyes are a lot older than yours!

Comment: @J.Musser blimey, herbicide, of course I meant pesticide. I shall alter that, must have been on automatic pilot when I typed it. Not sure if its necessary or not to use pesticide, depends if its eating too much of the plant. By the way, I only have a dumbphone and a tablet, no smartphone.